# How to display particular set of wordpress post on a webpage?

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have a **wordpress/php** code as shown below which display list of posts on a webpage.

Php code:

```
$special_reports = new \WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'cpac-special-report',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2 ? 3 : 4
]);
```

On debug `<?php echo json_encode($special_reports); ?>` it displays the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "post_type": "cpac-special-report",
        "orderby": "menu_order",
        "order": "ASC",
        "fields": "ids"
    },
    "posts": [149443, 149551, 149488],   /* Posts id here is displaying on the basis of weight order ASC */
    "max_num_pages": 54
}
```

What I want now in the following php, I want **post id 149443** to show up at **Line A** and **post ids 149551 and 149488** at **Line B**.

```
<?php if ($data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2) { ?>

<?php if ($special_reports->have_posts()) : while ($special_reports->have_posts()) : $special_reports->the_post(); ?>
          // Here I want to display post id 149443 (lets call as tile A)                         /* Line A */     
<?php endwhile; endif;

<div class ="test">
    <p>Some Content</p> // Here I am displaying tile B          
</div>

<?php if ($special_reports->have_posts()) : while ($special_reports->have_posts()) : $special_reports->the_post(); ?>
         // Here I want to display post ids 149551 and  149488  (lets call as tiles C and D)    /* Line B */    
<?php endwhile; endif;

<?php                   
}                   
?>
```

The graphical representation of the above php code should be:

```
Tile A   Tile B       Tile C   Tile D
149443   Some Content 149551   149488
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that **1st post id 149443 displays at Line A** and **2nd/3rd post ids (149551 and 149488) display at Line B**.

Answer (score 0):

To display post id 149443, inside the first `while()` loop just use `if ( get_the_ID() == 149433 )` and for the others use `if ( get_the_ID() != 149433 )`. The trick is to rewind the loop between the 2 uses so that you can use it again, so after the first loop use `$special_reports->rewind_posts();`